# Upload in Laravel inside another Controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, upload

I'm working with two tables

A line table has:

- Id
- Name
- Description

A Product table has:

- Id
- Name
- Description
- Line ID

So, I have a Line view to insert the name and description, also, bellow this form, I have a button to add a new product.

This button opens a modal with another form (name, description, file input) for create a product.

Therefore, I'm confuse.

1 - Do I have to create the product, but without any Line ID?

2 - How can I send the product data to Line view after create the new product? (I  have to use Ajax)

3 - Do I have to save the line data with all products together?

Line Form

[image: Line Form]

Product Modal Form

[image: Product Modal Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - Do I have to create the product, but without any Line ID?

**Answer**: Does the product need to have a `Line` before you can add it? Usually the answer to this is, have the user create the line **first** and then the product. So for example, `Macbook Pro` as a product. The user will **first** need to create a line called `Apple`, then he can create the product and choose Apple.

---

> 2 - How can I send the product data to Line view after create the new product? (I have to use Ajax)

**Answer**: You can do everything within the same controller. Just fetch the product/line data within the controller, and send it all the the view. If you're looking to do it through Ajax, just create a controller and route for example: `/api/products/all` which returns a list of all the products. Or you can also do: `/api/products/store` to store products, and within the controller return the product that was saved back to ajax call.

---

> 3 - Do I have to save the line data with all products together?

**Answer**: No, usually you save the line data first, then the product data follows.